# CSS descendant selection with duplicate modifier

Tags: css, css-selectors, nested-sortable

What is wrong with the following way of trying to apply a modifier ('active') to one specific element in a list? This is part of a nested sortable list whose branches as well as nodes are sortable and require the sortitem class. In the example the first 'X' should be highlighted with orange but it is not. I would expect CSS not to be confused by this, or is it? There is definitely something to learn for me here ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .class-0 {
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.80);
        left: 0.5%;
        top: 1%;
        height: 98%;
        width: 26%;
    }
    .class-0 .sortitem {
        font-size: 33px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        margin-right: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .class-0 .sortitem .bt {
        background: #55f;
        font-size: 29px;
    }
    .class-0 .sortitem .bt .active{
        background: #ff9b00;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="class-0">
    <span class="sortitem">
        <span class="sortcont">
            <span class="sortitem bt active"><span>X</span></span>
            <span class="sortitem bt"><span>X</span></span>
            <span class="sortitem bt"><span>X</span></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question has been marked as duplicate but I believe this is wrong. It assumes the one that asks would have know that one can actually separate or join css selectors which is something she or he might be unaware of

Comment: If you think that this is a different question, please edit your question to contain more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between the `.bt` and `.active`

```
.class-0 .sortitem .bt.active{
    background: #ff9b00;
}
```

By removing the space between the two class selectors, you are applying the style to elements with **both** `.bt` and `.active` classes. With the space between them, you are applying the style to elements with the `.active` class that are **inside** the elements with the `.bt` class.